# How do I reset hitpoints after fight

Tags: python, pygame

I've been programming my own adventure game and after the enemy or hero is defeated the hitpoints stays at 0 and I want to set it back because if the hero fights again, the enemy stays dead.

I've tried both data classes and dictionaries but it didn't work out

```
def create_enemy_dic(self):
    enemy_dic = {
        "name": "Enemy",
        "lvl": 1,
        "lvlnext" : 25,
        "reward" : 25,
        "stats" : {
            "str" : 1, 
            "dex" : 1,
            "int" : 1,
            "hp" : 30,
            "atk" : [5, 9]
        }
    }
```

### return(enemy_dic)

```
def take_dmg(self):
    self.hitpoints_enemy = self.enemy_dic["stats"]["hp"]
    dmg_atk = random.randint(self.hero_dic["stats"]["atk"][0], self.hero_dic["stats"]["atk"][1])
    dmg_def = random.randint(self.enemy_dic["stats"]["atk"][0], self.enemy_dic["stats"]["atk"][1])
    self.hitpoints_enemy -= dmg_atk
    self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] -= dmg_def
    print(self.enemy_dic)
    if self.defender:
        if self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] <= 0:
            self.draw_dmg("{} has been slain.".format(self.hero_dic["name"]), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("press any key to quit.", 200, 200)
            self.fighting = False
            self.done01 = True
        else:
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.hero_dic["name"], dmg_def), 200, 200)
            self.defender = False
    elif self.attacker:
        if self.hitpoints_enemy <= 0:
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.enemy_dic["name"], dmg_atk), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("{} has been slain.".format(self.enemy_dic["name"]), 200, 200)
            self.hero_dic["xp"] += self.enemy_dic["reward"] 
            self.draw_dmg("{} has gained {} experience".format(self.hero_dic["name"], self.hero_dic["xp"]), 200, 200)
            FIGHTING = False
            self.done01 = True
        if self.hero_dic["xp"] >= self.hero_dic["lvlnext"]:
            self.hero_dic["lvl"] += 1
            self.hero_dic["xp"] = self.hero_dic["xp"] - self.hero_dic["lvlnext"]
            self.hero_dic["lvlnext"] = round(self.hero_dic["lvlnext"] * 1.5)
            self.draw_dmg("{} has reached level {}".format(self.hero_dic["name"], self.hero_dic["lvl"]), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("press any key to quit.", 200, 200)
            self.fighting = False
            self.done01 = True
        else:
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.enemy_dic["name"], dmg_atk), 200, 200)
            self.defender = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need two variables for hit points.
One for the max hit points (the hit point of a non wounded enemy) and one for the current hit points.

If you add to the stats dict a ["max_hp"] field, then resetting the hitpounts would then just be:

```
self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] = self.hero_dic["stats"]["max_hp"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `max_hp` (or `base_hp`?) attribute to your enemy/player, and then when you're less than (or equal to) 0, just simply set the `hp` to the `max_hp`

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest storing the maximum hero health as a hero property, such as:

```
self.hero_dic["stats"]["max_hp"]
```

Then, you just need to set back the hero life as soon as you detect that the hero is dead or the enemy is dead. Consider the following modifications to your code:

```
def take_dmg(self):
    self.hitpoints_enemy = self.enemy_dic["stats"]["hp"]
    dmg_atk = random.randint(self.hero_dic["stats"]["atk"][0], self.hero_dic["stats"]["atk"][1])
    dmg_def = random.randint(self.enemy_dic["stats"]["atk"][0], self.enemy_dic["stats"]["atk"][1])
    self.hitpoints_enemy -= dmg_atk
    self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] -= dmg_def
    print(self.enemy_dic)

    if self.defender:
        if self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] <= 0:
            # Hero has been slained
            self.draw_dmg("{} has been slain.".format(self.hero_dic["name"]), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("press any key to quit.", 200, 200)

            # Update hero health
            self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] = self.hero_dic["stats"]["max_hp"]

            # Update game status
            self.fighting = False
            self.done01 = True
        else:
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.hero_dic["name"], dmg_def), 200, 200)
            self.defender = False
    elif self.attacker:
        if self.hitpoints_enemy <= 0:
            # Enemy has been slained
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.enemy_dic["name"], dmg_atk), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("{} has been slain.".format(self.enemy_dic["name"]), 200, 200)

            # Update hero stats and health
            self.hero_dic["stats"]["hp"] = self.hero_dic["stats"]["max_hp"]
            self.hero_dic["xp"] += self.enemy_dic["reward"] 
            self.draw_dmg("{} has gained {} experience".format(self.hero_dic["name"], self.hero_dic["xp"]), 200, 200)

            # Update game status
            FIGHTING = False
            self.done01 = True
        if self.hero_dic["xp"] >= self.hero_dic["lvlnext"]:
            self.hero_dic["lvl"] += 1
            self.hero_dic["xp"] = self.hero_dic["xp"] - self.hero_dic["lvlnext"]
            self.hero_dic["lvlnext"] = round(self.hero_dic["lvlnext"] * 1.5)
            self.draw_dmg("{} has reached level {}".format(self.hero_dic["name"], self.hero_dic["lvl"]), 200, 200)
            self.draw_dmg("press any key to quit.", 200, 200)
            self.fighting = False
            self.done01 = True
        else:
            self.draw_dmg("{} takes {} damage!".format(self.enemy_dic["name"], dmg_atk), 200, 200)
            self.defender = True
```